# Why won't Blender run on Windows XP?

Tags: windows, installation, compatibility

I downloaded Blender 64 bit and the OS indicated that the program was not compatible with my computer chip. I then downloaded the 32 bit version which seemed to allow me to install. However the blender Icon in windows when pressed informs me that the program is not a window application. I have an Intel(R) Core (TM)2 Duo CPU E7300 @2.66Ghz if that is important and I am running XP. I am fairly sure I am doing something wrong here- can anyone help please?

Answer (score 16):

The last version of blender that was officially compatible with Windows XP was blender 2.76. Versions after that probably won't work. You can download previous version of blender [here](http://download.blender.org/release/).

To quote Martijn Berger (a blender developer) from [here](https://lists.blender.org/pipermail/bf-committers/2016-February/046812.html) on why support for XP was dropped:

> We implicitly dropped Windows XP when switching to python 3.5. Python
>   has the so called PEP system and PEP 11 "Removing support for little
>   used platforms" defines the support for windows XP to be over at the
>   same time Microsoft stopped supporting it. Since python 3.5 released
>   after XP died it does not support XP.
>
> While it might be possible to backport python 3.5 to windows XP i
>   think that we should not do this.
>
> So blender 2.77 will not run on XP. The 32 bit release requires Vista
>   or newer and the 64 bit release Windows 7 SP1 or newer.

Comment: @JWarren If this answer has helped you then feel free to accept this answer by clicking the tick icon next to the answer. See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: The last version that runs on **WindowsXP 64** is **2.70a**. I got an old xp workstation and tested all versions up to 2.76 without success.