# Install blender on Windows XP

Tags: installation

I want to install blender on my old computer running Windows XP. I have installed the 2.76 version, but it did not install. I tried to remove it, but it is giving me an error again:

**"The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. this may indicate a problem with the package. the error code is 2753"**

I have a PC Dual Core with 4 GB ram.  Which version can i install?  It must be near the latest and support Windows XP. Please have a link to download.

Comment: 32 bit or 64 bit? The last version that runs on WindowsXP 64 is 2.70a, further info: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57454/why-wont-blender-run-on-windows-xp

Answer (score 3):

XP support was removed in [2.77](https://www.blender.org/features/past-releases/2-77/):

> Support for Windows XP and the SCons build system was removed.

**2.76b** was the last version to support Windows XP.

**blender-2.76b-windows** variants are available from [download.blender.org/release/Blender2.76/](http://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.76/).

There might be installer-related issues, so I recommend the `.zip` versions.

Comment: thanks for replying i got this message the procedure entry point gett.logicalprocessorinformation could not be located in the dynamic link library kernel32.dll and i click ok the installation fail. what should i do?

Comment: So, even with the zip version, starting blender.exe gives you errors like that above? If yes, I guess your kernel32.dll could be damaged or else... can you try the zip on another pc? This seems to happen also using Skype (https://community.skype.com/t5/Windows-desktop-client/GetLogicalProcessorInformation-Kernel32-dll-XP-SP2-Workaround/td-p/3454981), which Service Pack have you installed? Based on that, I guess SP3 is needed...

Comment: yes sP3 but i dont use skype i use bluestack

Comment: yes, that skype reference is just showing the same problem... I would try to reapply sp3. Or, try on another pc. It is a low level, operating-system level error which causing the issue... not blender, imho.