# What is the Latest Version under WinXP?

Tags: game-engine, blender-internal-render-engine

What is the Latest Version under WinXP?
I download the Installer and it says WinXP not supported.

Please tell me what latest or most-good Version of Blender is running under WinXP?

Thank you!

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64693/install-blender-on-windows-xp

Comment: 1st step: https://www.google.com/search?q=blender+windows+xp, 2nd step: open first link: https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/, 3rd step: read: `Blender 2.76 and earlier still supports Windows XP and OpenGL 1.4 graphics cards.`